# Error when exporting a graphic to svg, network error?

Tags: highcharts

Update the Highcharts version to 11.3.0, the dog I have is when export uses avg graphics, I get a network problem, I already tried on different machines and it's the same error [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHlVp.png)

code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Corn vs wheat estimated production for 2020',
        align: 'left'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text:
            'Source: <a target="_blank" ' +
            'href="https://www.indexmundi.com/agriculture/?commodity=corn">indexmundi</a>',
        align: 'left'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['USA', 'China', 'Brazil', 'EU', 'India', 'Russia'],
        crosshair: true,
        accessibility: {
            description: 'Countries'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: '1000 metric tons (MT)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' (1000 MT)'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    exporting: {
        filename: 'graficas2'
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Corn',
            data: [406292, 260000, 107000, 68300, 27500, 14500]
        },
        {
            name: 'Wheat',
            data: [51086, 136000, 5500, 141000, 107180, 77000]
        }
    ]
});
```

I would like to know if it's my mistake or a higchart mistake

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the exporting module v11.3 which is reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/20376 You can add your comments and example in the github thread.

As a workaround, you use Highcharts v11.2:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/11.2/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/11.2/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nmgyfkjb/